# Can't convert response from Sqlalchemy to Pydantic model

Tags: python, validation, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to return a schema that inherits from Pydantic's BaseModel but I'm getting an error

Models:

```
class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(60), nullable=False)
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    created_at: Mapped[date] = mapped_column(default=date.today())

    profiles: Mapped['Profile'] = relationship(
        back_populates='projects',
        secondary='project_profiles'
    )
    problems: Mapped[list['Problem']] = relationship(
        back_populates='project'
    )
```

Schemas:

```
class SProjectDetail(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    description: str
    created_at: date
    profiles: Optional[list[SProfile]] = []
    problems: Optional[list[SProblem]] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class SProblem(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str

class SProfile(BaseModel):
    id: int
    lastname: str
    firstname: str
```

DAO:

```
class ProjectDAO(BaseDAO):
    model = Project

    @classmethod
    async def find_by_id(cls, id):
        async with async_session_maker() as session:
            query = select(Project,
                           Problem, 
                           Profile      
            ).outerjoin(
                Problem, Project.id == Problem.project_id
            ).outerjoin(
                Profile
            ).where(
                Project.id == id
            )

           
            print(query)
            result = await session.execute(query)
            return result.scalars().all()
```

Router:

```
@router.get('/{id}')
async def get_project_by_id(id: int = Path(..., ge=0)) -> list[SProjectDetail]:
    return await ProjectDAO.find_by_id(id)
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAKln.png)

I tried to remove pydantic schemas from the router response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjqVw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can read about this error here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/errors.html#error-bhk3

*This error message means that an object has become de-associated with its Session and is being asked to lazy load data from the database.*

So, you try to read it as a Pydantic, while it's lazily loaded, and your Session is already closed in `ProjectDao`.
You can either read it as a Pydantic model inside the `find_by_id` method, or you can use the `Depends(Session)` from `SQLModel`. This works quite nice. There is a good example here: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/fastapi/session-with-dependency/#the-with-block.